# gcc linker (ld) can't find shared libraries

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, cross-compiling, ld

I've trying to cross compile an app for iMX6 CPU using linaro-gcc and a dedicated rootfs. The app might be linked to OpenVG and the standard pthread libraries.

It compiles fine but the linker failed to link to the OpenVG library so I added the linker switch ***-L/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/usr/lib*** and now it links to the OpenVG library. But since then, it can't link to pthread library even with the linker swtich ***-L/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/lib***.

The error message is :

```
../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0
../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
```

Those libraries are in the ***/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/lib*** directory.

Here's the LDFLAGS var.

```
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lOpenVG -L/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/lib -L/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/usr/lib
```

Does anyone know why ld can't link to those libraries even if I added the -L switch to tell it where to find them?

**edit April 30, 2015 at 16:55**
I used strace to find what's going on... I don't know what's going on but it tries to open libpthread.so in several dirs even in the right ones but it does not link with it.
Here's the output.

```
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/lib/libpthread.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/lib/libpthread.a", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.so", O_RDONLY) = 4
open("/home/ae/Documents/toradex/col-imx6/colibri-imx6-sdk/usr/lib/libpthread.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Maybe you are not using the cross-linker but the native one. And also remember that if you use GCC, you should use `gcc` (or the cross-compiler variant) as the linker instead of `ld`.

Comment: @rodrigo: I do use the cross gcc and the cross ld. linker used is ../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld as described in the message and this is the linker that comes with the linaro gcc for arm CPUs. I do also link using the cross GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this issue using the compiler and linker switch [--sysroot](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) so the linker and the compiler both work using the arm rootfs as base directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, running ld with `--verbose` showed it was trying to open the **libstatic.a** (which didn't exist) instead of my intended **libdynamic.so**. I fixed it with `-Bdynamic`.

This was using [ARM's toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a) for arhmf.